# Django Upgrade to 1.8.3 issues

Tags: django

I upgraded to Django to 1.8.3, and i hit this error:

```
from django_nose.runner import *
File "/blah/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_nose/runner.py", line 22, in <module>
from django.db.backends.creation import BaseDatabaseCreation
ImportError: No module named creation
```

I looked around for solutions, but could not find any. Is there a way to fix this issue ?

Fyi, i did a

```
pip install django==1.8.3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#database-backend-api), would you?

Comment: I edited my question. The problem seems to be with django_nose.

Comment: *Which version* of `django_nose`?

Comment: django-nose Version: 1.4.1

Comment: And that's the one you were using when you got the error? Then raise a bug report with the developers.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe upgrading django_nose will work (version 1.4 has Django 1.8 support [according to the changelog](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose/blob/master/changelog.rst))

```
pip install django_nose --upgrade
```

Comment: Just upgrading django_nose fixed my problem. Thank for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
from django.db.backends.creation import BaseDatabaseCreation
```

To:

```
from django.db.backends.base.creation import BaseDatabaseCreation
```

Comment: You are right about the change. But unfortunately, the issue is in django_nose. I can fix it up, but would be nice if django had a fix for it. I wanted to know if anyone faced this issue, and what is the right way to get around it.

Comment: Go to Django nose's github project, and see if there's issues or pull requests about it